# Как менять места байтов в переменной dw?

Tags: ассемблер

Есть у нас

```
X DW ?    ; ? — это любое значение.
```

Как знаем, тип `DW` занимает 2 байта (1 слово).
Как можно менять местами байты?

- `|Byte1 | Byte2| = 1 word`
- `|Byte2 | Byte1| = 1 word` (уже другой будет)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этого вращение на один байт:

```
ror ax, 8               ; Вместо ax может быть любой другой двухбайтный регистр
ror word ptr [адрес], 8 ; А можно и так
```

В данном случае вращение вытеснит старший байт и поставит его на место младшего.

Кстати, вращать можно в любую сторону. То есть эта команда тоже сработает:

```
rol ax, 8
```

**P. S.:** Еcли же потребуется развернуть уже четырёхбайтную величину,  используйте `bswap`.